# Java Spring FormFactory.form with nested Objects

Tags: java, spring

I have the following form model:

ReservationLockRequestForm:

```
public class ReservationLockRequestForm {
    private Restaurant restaurant;
    private ReservationInquiryResponse reservationData;
    private Time reservationTime;
}
```

I left out the getters, setters and empty constructor for legibility.

Now, If i call this

```
formFactory.form(ReservationLockRequestForm.class).bindFromRequest().get()
```

I get

```
Invalid property 'restaurant[tables][1][numberOfChairs]' of bean class [models.helpers.forms.ReservationLockRequestForm]: Illegal attempt to get property 'restaurant' threw exception
```

The `Restaurant` Model contains a `List<Tables>` object, and the `Tables` model does contain a `numberOfChairs` property.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Adding a Breakpoint in the `ReservationLockRequestForm` `Restataurant Setter` revels that the incoming `Restaurant` object is empty (all properties are null), but a quick check of the request revels that it contains all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I fixed it. Turns out the Front-End was sending the request as Form-Data, not as JSON. I changed that, and without any modifications to the Back-End it worked flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom property editor. You'll need to have a class which extends `PropertyEditorSupport` e.g. `RestaurantPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport`, which is responsible for converting restaurant, or whichever field to and from text representation. It will need to override `setAsText` and `getAsText`.

Then in your controller which returns the view, you will need to have

```
@InitBinder("reservationLockRequestForm ")
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder)
{
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Restaurant .class, new RestaurantPropertyEditor());
    // ... other ones too
}
```

Often your `PropertyEditor` will need your dao to convert from an id to an entity and vice versa, you'll need to do all this yourself.

Sometimes it is easier not to use Spring Binding directly with your entity and manually handling the request parameters from the post/get. Keep that in mind, I find this is the case for dealing with parameters which are collections.